# Query on Inner and Outer object at same time Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have two objects **ConversationModel** and  **MessageModel** as follows

```
class ConversationModel: Object, NSCoding {

@objc dynamic var conversation_id : String?
@objc dynamic var display_name : String?
@objc dynamic var to_jid : String?
@objc dynamic var from_jid : String?
@objc dynamic var unread_count : Int = 0
@objc dynamic var last_timestamp : String?
@objc dynamic var group_name : String?
@objc dynamic var group_id : String?
@objc dynamic var ghost_name : String?
@objc dynamic var ghost_password : String?
@objc dynamic var ghost_message : String?
@objc dynamic var user_profile_image : String?
@objc dynamic var last_message_status : String?
@objc dynamic var m_body : String?
@objc dynamic var sender_timestamp : String?
@objc dynamic var m_type : String?
@objc dynamic var receiver_timestamp : String?
@objc dynamic var userCustomProfileImageUrl: String?
@objc dynamic var profileImageUrl: String?
@objc dynamic var userImageHashKey: String?
@objc dynamic var userImageBase64String : String?
@objc dynamic var sender_jid : String?
@objc dynamic var reciever_jid: String?
@objc dynamic var sending_status: String?
@objc dynamic var is_blocked : Bool = false
@objc dynamic var is_business : Bool = false
@objc dynamic var is_ghost_enable : Bool = false
@objc dynamic var is_deleted : Bool = false
@objc dynamic var is_offline : Bool = false
@objc dynamic var is_archive : Bool = false
@objc dynamic var is_group : Bool = false
@objc dynamic var is_pin : Bool = false
@objc dynamic var is_mute : Bool = false
@objc dynamic var mute_time : String?
@objc dynamic var dataForImage : Data?
@objc dynamic var phoneNumber: String?
@objc dynamic var is_removed: Bool = false
@objc dynamic var audio_playedtime :String?
@objc dynamic var userThumbnailImage : String?

var messagesList = List<MessageModel>()
}
```

**And Message Model is**

```
class MessageModel: Object, NSCoding {

@objc dynamic var burning_msg_timestamp: String?
@objc dynamic var is_burning_msg : Int = 0
@objc dynamic var delivered_timestamp: String?
@objc dynamic var read_timestamp: String?
@objc dynamic var message_id: String?
@objc dynamic var reciever_id: String?
@objc dynamic var conversation_id: String?
@objc dynamic var body: String?
@objc dynamic var url: String?
@objc dynamic var sender_timestamp: CLong = 0
@objc dynamic var receiver_timestamp: String?
@objc dynamic var forward_tag: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var message_type: String?
@objc dynamic var stanza_id: String?
@objc dynamic var selected_message_reply_id: String?
@objc dynamic var burn_time: String?
@objc dynamic var schedule_timestamp: String?
@objc dynamic var is_scheduled: Bool = false
@objc dynamic var room_jid: String?
@objc dynamic var sender_jid: String?
@objc dynamic var is_deleted: Bool = false
}
```

I would like to fetch all conversation  with `is_archive == false`  and only those `messageslist` with `is_deleted = false`

I am trying to fetch with this code but its only filtering ConversationModel and not applying filter on Message Model

```
    var result = realm.objects(ConversationModel.self).filter("is_archive = \(is_archive) 
   AND ANY messagesList.is_deleted == \(boolFalse) AND ANY messagesList.sender_timestamp <= 
   \(timeStamp)").sorted(byKeyPath: "last_timestamp", ascending: false)
```

I have tried Nested queries but unable to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer but more confirmation that your code is correct and working as intended.

To test, I copy and pasted your code and created sample data and added an _id object to ConversationModel so I could tell which was being retrieved by the query.

So we have three conversations, each having a message. The goal is for the query to retrieve conversation c1; its is_archive is false, it has a message where is_deleted is false and a sender_timestamp <= 5

```
let c0 = ConversationModel()
c0._id = "c0"
c0.is_archive = true

let c1 = ConversationModel()
c1._id = "c1"
c1.is_archive = false

let c2 = ConversationModel()
c2._id = "c2"
c2.is_archive = false

let m0 = MessageModel()
let m1 = MessageModel()
let m2 = MessageModel()

m0.sender_timestamp = 0
m1.sender_timestamp = 1
m2.sender_timestamp = 2

m0.is_deleted = true
m1.is_deleted = false
m2.is_deleted = true

c0.messagesList.append(m0)
c1.messagesList.append(m1)
c2.messagesList.append(m2)

try! realm.write {
   realm.add([c0, c1, c2])
}
```

Then I ran your query, adding vars.

```
let is_archive = false
let boolFalse = false
let timeStamp = 5
            
var results = realm.objects(ConversationModel.self).filter("is_archive = \(is_archive) AND ANY messagesList.is_deleted == \(boolFalse) AND ANY messagesList.sender_timestamp <= \(timeStamp)").sorted(byKeyPath: "last_timestamp", ascending: false)
```

which produced this output

```
c1
```

Comment: thank you Jay for your answer, But my question is little deferent. lets suppose I have 3 conversation and 20 messages in each conversation, Now I would like to fetch conversation where is_Archive == false and inside conversation only those messages who have is_deleted false. In your query I am retrieving all messages inside each conversation

Comment: @MatloobHasnain Umm. I copy and pasted the query from your question so it's the exact same query. If what's asked in your question wasn't actually the question, please update the question with what you are actually looking to do. Perhaps you want to query to retrieve the messages themselves, not the conversations? e.g. if you retrieve an object, you get EVERYTHING inside that object as well. So if you retrieve a conversation object, all of it's messages are part of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't specify MessageMode constraints in your ConversationModel query. What you can do is create a lazy property consisting of MessageModel objects with constraints on the is_deleted and sender_timestamp properties.

```
class ConversationModel: Object {

    // all other properties ...

    var messagesList = List<MessageModel>()

    lazy var activeMessages: Results<MessageModel> = {
        return messagesList
            .filter(.notDeleted)
            .filter(.sentOnOrBefore(SOME_TIMESTAMP))
    }()

    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["activeMessages"]
    }
}
```

Personally, I like to organize my filter constraints like this:

```
extension NSPredicate {

    static let notArchived = NSPredicate(format: "is_archive == false")

    static let notDeleted = NSPredicate(format: "is_deleted == false")

    static func sentOnOrBefore(_ timestamp: CLong) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSPredicate(format: "sender_timestamp <= %d", timestamp)
    }
}

extension SortDescriptor {
    static let lastTimestampDescending = SortDescriptor(keyPath: "last_timestamp", ascending: false)
}
```

To fetch the Conversations we can do this:

```
func fetchConversations() throws -> Results<ConversationModel> {
    let realm = try Realm()
    return realm.objects(ConversationModel.self)
        .filter(.notArchived)
        .sorted(by: [.lastTimestampDescending])
}
```

Then to access the constrained messages on each conversation we can do something like this:

```
func processMessages(for conversations: Results<ConversationModel>) {
    for conversation in conversations {
        print(conversation.activeMessages)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I like this answer but I don't think it answers the actual question. If you look at the posters comments it appears they want to return conversation objects with a List that only contain messages that only match certain criteria - e.g. get the conversations whose messages match the query and only return those conversations and those messages. Obviously those would actually be different objects since their List properties would be different. I am hoping they will clarify what's being asked.